# Symfony - How to use route for form submission using Sweet Alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, symfony, sweetalert

**EDIT:** How can I confirm submission of a selected user id in a form of a Sweet Alert? See, I have this table which displays all the registered users in my webpage. My problem is I don't know how to generate Symfony's route to a `<button>` tag in my twig template. I can't use `<a>` tag because SWAL only executes when `data-type` is use and it's only available in `<button>` tag, which can't use a `href` attribute like `href="{{ path('path_to_route') }}"`. I also had problem calling for the `{{ user.id }}` because it doesn't get the user id of the button I selected. I have this code from various sources but still there's somethings wrong. Badly need help!

**UPDATE:** I can't download FOSJsRoutingBundle because we are working in a company with some installation restriction and unfortunately, installing a Bundle is part of it. Is there any alternative?

My Twig:

```
<div class="row clearfix js-sweetalert">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-warning waves-effect" data-type="cancel"><i class="material-icons">build</i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" data-type="delete-user" data-userId="{{ user.id }}"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function deleteUserAction($id)
    {
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->findUserBy(['id' => $id]);

        if ($user ==  null) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('User not found for user' . $user);
        }

        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

        $userManager->deleteUser($user);

        $this->setFlash('user_deleted', $user . ' has been successfully deleted!');

        $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_userList'); 

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
```

This is my Sweet Alert script:

```
$(function () {
$('.js-sweetalert button').on('click', function () {
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    if (type === 'basic') {
        showBasicMessage();
    }
    else if (type === 'delete-user') {
        var userId = $(this).data('userId');
        showDeleteUserMessage();
    }
function showDeleteUserMessage() {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure you want to delete this user?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this user",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            var data = {id : userId};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ path('fos_user_deleteUser') }}",
                data: data,
                success: function(data, dataType) {
                    swal("Deleted", "The user has been removed from the Database", "Success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
                    }
                });
        } else {}
    });
}
```

Comment: plz add your html code here

Comment: twig have been added

Answer (score 1):

you can generate routes in your Javascript code with the [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html) or move your js-code into a twig-template to use the path twig function

Comment: can you include an example code from what you said is moving my js-code into a twig-template?

Comment: your template would look like this: {%block content%}your sweet alert section comes here{%endblock%}{%block javascript%} your javascript-code comes here{%endblock%}

Comment: That's what I did. Now, I transferred it to it's own external script (mySweetAlert.js). It's not affecting other dropdown buttons now but still, the problem of not reloading the page to the new updated users table without the deleted user is not fix.

Answer (score 1):

In html add the user id

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" data-userId="1" data-type="delete-user"><i class="material-icons">delete forever</i></button>
```

at the time of button click u need to take the user id value and pass it through the function

```
var type = $(this).data('type');
if (type === 'delete-user') {
  var userId = $(this).data('userId');
    showDeleteUserMessage(userId);
}
```

Inside the function(isConfirm) u can call ajax

```
 if (isConfirm) {
      //ajax request here
   var data = {id : userId};  //u need to post  id

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('fos_user_deleteUser') }}",
        data: data,
        success: function(data, dataType)
        {
            alert(data);
        },

        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        }

    } else {
        swal("Cancelled", "not deleting", "error");
    }
```

plz check ur js file open an close braces

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that comment of yours saying `//u need to post id`. Where did you get that `#userId`?

Comment: When I click confirm delete, it doesn't do anything and it doesn't throw the error too. Can you complete the opening and closing of braces from function showdeleteUserMessage() to the end?

Comment: This is my code from on success: `success: function(data, dataType) {
                    swal("Deleted", "The user has been removed from the Database", "Success");
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
                    }
            });
        } else {}
    });`

Comment: I have tried your code but still it doesn't work. It's stuck with the swal prompt but it doesn't confirm or delete anything when I click the confirm button. I think there's a problem with the calling of the `{{ user.id }}` and the routing maybe. Pls do reply for clarification.